# Difference between static block and assigning static in class?

Tags: java, static

Is there any difference between following two initializations of static variables:

```
class Class1 {    
    private static Var var;

    static {
        var = getSingletonVar();
    }  
}
```

---

```
class Class2 {
    private static var = getSingletonVar;
}
```

Are these two different ways of initializing a static variable functionally the same?

Comment: Yes. The result will be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, its functionally the same.

From [Java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

```
There is an alternative to static blocks — you can write a private static method:

class Whatever {
    public static varType myVar = initializeClassVariable();

    private static varType initializeClassVariable() {

        // initialization code goes here
    }
}

The advantage of private static methods is that they can be reused later if you need to reinitialize the class variable.
```

Answer (score 1):

The result will be same.

In both the cases static variable will get initialized with class loading.

static methods and static class blocks are two different things.
static methods need to be called where as static class block automatically gets executed with class loading.

Answer (score 0):

First Thing you haven't declared static methods here.
probably if you want know order of execution

```
1) constructors
```

Invoked when you create an instance, totally independent of when #2 happens, or even if it ever happens at all

```
2)static methods
```

Invoked when you invoke them, totally independent of when #1 happens, or even if it ever happens at all

```
3)static blocks
```

Invoked when the class is initialized, which happens before #1 or #2 can happen.

Answer (score 0):

Static initializers and static blocks both run when the class is initialized. Static blocks exist because sometimes you want to do something at initialization time that can't be characterized as a simple assignment:

```
static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ThisClass.class);
static final String PROPS_FILE = "/some/file.properties";
static final Properties gProps;
static {
    gProps = new Properties();
    try {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(PROPS_FILE);
        try {
            gProps.load(reader);
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new SomeException("Failed to load properties from " + PROPS_FILE, e);
    }
    log.info(ThisClass.class.getName() + " Loaded");
}
```